# How to attach image in website form to appear in backend binary field for odoo

Tags: python, html, odoo

Thanks for your help in advance.

I would like to attach image in my web form and let it appear in binary field in odoo11. Below is my code but something is wrong with it, right now the attached image goes to ir.attachments only.

HTML code for attached button

```
<div class="form-group form-field">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 text-right-not-xs">
        <label class="control-label" for="image_attach"> Image </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-8">
        <input type="file" class="form-control o_website_form_input" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="image_attach"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

PY code for binary field

```
image_attach = fields.Binary('Image')
```

I have tried to add attachment=True nothing happened as well.

XML code for the binary field

```
<field name=" image_attach " widget="image" class="oe_left oe_avatar"/>
```

http controller code

```
from odoo import http

class Image(http.Controller):
    def index(self, **kw):
        vals = {}
        if post['image_attach']:
            vals.update({'image_attach': base64.encodestring(post['image_attach'].read())})
        request.registry['hr.image'].write(cr, uid, vals)
```

Hoping someone could help me to find out what is wrong in my coding and solve this issue, thanks.